# How to get an element (struct) in an array by a value in the struct

Tags: c++, arrays, struct, operator-overloading, overloading

Let's say I have this struct containing an integer.

```
struct Element 
{
  int number;
  Element(int number) 
  {
    this->number = number;
  }
};
```

And I'm gonna create a vector containing many Element structs.

```
std::vector<Element> array;
```

Pretend that all the Element structs inside array have been initialized and have their number variable set.
My question is how can I instantly get an element based on the variable number?

It is very possible to do it with a for loop, but I'm currently focusing on optimization and trying to avoid as many for loops as possible.

I want it to be as instant as getting by index:

```
Element wanted_element = array[wanted_number]
```

There must be some kind of overloading stuff, but I don't really know what operators or stuff to overload.

Any help is appreciated :)

Comment: You can't, at least not with the types you've provided.

Comment: are you willing to use a hashmap?

Comment: Tip: You can make your example code shorter (less intrusive) by simplifying your constructor to one line: `Element(int number) : number(number) {}`

Comment: *"My question is how can I instantly get an element based on the variable number?"* -- nothing in a program is instant. I think you mean "constant time", as opposed to the linear time it takes to iterate over a vector.

Comment: *"There must be some kind of overloading stuff, but I don't really know what operators or stuff to overload."* -- overloading does not affect time complexity. You could define an a vector-like container whose `operator[]` looks up an element by `.number` instead of by position, but that operator might still be an O(n) operation. You wouldn't see the loop when using the operator, but it's still there.

Answer (score 0):

With comparator overloading implemented, std::find is available to help:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>
struct Element 
{
  int number;
  Element(int number) 
  {
    this->number = number;
  }

  bool operator == (Element el)
  {
      return number == el.number;
  }

};


int main()
{

    std::vector<Element> array;
    std::vector<int> test;
    for(int i=0;i<100;i++)
    {
        auto t = clock();
        test.push_back(t);
        array.push_back(Element(t));
    }
    auto valToFind = test[test.size()/2];
    std::cout << "value to find: "<<valToFind<<std::endl;
    Element toFind(valToFind);
    auto it = std::find(array.begin(),array.end(),toFind);
    if(it != array.end())
        std::cout<<"found:" << it->number <<std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

The performance on above method depends on the position of the searched value in the array. Non-existing values & last element values will take the highest time while first element will be found quickest.

If you need to optimize searching-time, you can use another data-structure instead of `vector`. For example, `std::map` is simple to use here and fast on average (compared to latest elements of vector-version):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>
#include <map>

struct Element 
{
  int number;
  Element(){ number = -1; }
  Element(int number) 
  {
    this->number = number;
  }

};


int main()
{

    std::map<int,Element> mp;
    std::vector<int> test;
    for(int i=0;i<100;i++)
    {
        auto t = clock();
        test.push_back(t);
        mp[t]=Element(t);
    }
    auto valToFind = test[test.size()/2];
    std::cout << "value to find: "<<valToFind<<std::endl;
    auto it = mp.find(valToFind);
    if(it != mp.end())
        std::cout<<"found:" << it->second.number <<std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

If you have to use vector, you can still use the map near the vector to keep track of its elements the same way above method just with extra memory space & extra deletions/updates on the map whenever vector is altered.

Anything you invent would with success would look like hashing or a tree in the end. std::unordered_map uses hashing while std::map uses red-black tree.

If range of values are very limited, like 0-to-1000 only, then simply saving its index in a second vector would be enough:

```
vec[number] = indexOfVector;
Element found = array[vec[number]];
```

If range is full and if you don't want to use any map nor unordered_map, you can still use a direct-mapped caching on the std::find method. On average, simple caching should decrease total time taken on duplicated searches (how often you search same item?).